# BP label error in AX7

Tags: label, axapta, erp, dynamics-ax7

Can someone guide me to why does this error popup

I have a model `SLD_HRApplicationFoundation`, which has a `SLD_HRP` label file. When I check for best practices, I get the following error

```
BP Rule: [BPErrorUnknownLabel]:Path: [dynamics://EdInt/SLD_HRRetirementAge]:Unknown label 
'@SLD_HRP:Param0014'. Legacy labels (such as label id @SYS12345) are case insensitive and 
modern labels (such as 'MyLabelId' in @MyLabelFile:MyLabelId) are case sensitive. Use upper 
casing when referring to legacy labels and exact casing for modern labels.
```

Where as my `SLD_HRP.en-US.label.txt` file has the following entry

```
Label ID: Param0014
Label: Default retirement age
Description: Help text for retirement age years
```

and the `properties` set for `SLD_HRRetirementAge` EDT as

```
Label: @SLD_HRP:Param0013
Help text: @SLD_HRP:Param0014
```

I am currently running `AX7 update 8` and `SLD_HRApplicationFoundation` model has been build to latest changes and database is synchronized as well.

Comment: Seems like you missed a character in label file name `SLD_HR.en-US.label.txt`. Should be `SLD_HRP.en-US.label.txt`

Comment: @AliaksandrMaksimau sorry that was a typo :p The actual file is ```SLD_HRP.en-US.label.txt```, updated mistake in question

Comment: Can you please verify if there is any space before or after Param0014 in label id.

Comment: @PradeepMuttikulangaraVasu nope, no such error. I have tried correcting it by copy pasting, re-writing, or even assigning it to other element property

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but since this issue is still occuring in the latest version (PU15):

Sometimes the model build does not seem to correctly update the label information. As Medhi Moalla suggests in his answer on your identical question in the AX community question [BP Label Error AX 7](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/248787), the following command line tool can be used to recreate the label .dll files:

Open

1. Open command line with (admin) privilege
2. Execute this command : `J:\AosService\PackagesLocalDirectory\bin\labelc.exe -metadata="J:\AosService\PackagesLocalDirectory" -output="J:\AosService\PackagesLocalDirectory\<Package Name>\Resources" -modelmodule="<Package Name>"`

Comment: Thanks for the late reply, but I understood why it happened back then. The label file was residing in another model, and I had to build the model that contained the label file for it to remove all the BP Rules.